# BarCodeScanner has stopped

Tags: java, android, adt, zxing

I'm trying to code my a Barcode Scanner, using the ZXing Library.

When I'm starting my App everything is OK.

After pressing the Scan Button, I'm getting an Pop-Up: "BarCodeScanner has stopped."

Logcat:

```html
10-12 10:51:57.674: I/PersonaManager(13977): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.050_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.050__release_AU ()
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.12.SPL
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): Local Branch: 
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.050
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): Local Patches: NONE
10-12 10:51:57.824: I/Adreno-EGL(13977): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
10-12 10:51:57.864: D/OpenGLRenderer(13977): Enabling debug mode 0
10-12 10:52:01.308: D/AndroidRuntime(13977): Shutting down VM
10-12 10:52:01.318: W/dalvikvm(13977): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418e9da0)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977): Process: com.example, PID: 13977
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
10-12 10:52:01.318: E/AndroidRuntime(13977):  ... 12 more
```

Here is my Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
     
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         
        <activity
               android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
               android:screenOrientation="landscape"
               android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
               android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
               <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               </intent-filter>
               <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: Manifest is in the first post.

Comment: Do you have ZXING application installed on your device where you are testing this app?

Comment: I have installed this application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import `Zxing` as library into your project.By looking at the error it seems that you are not adding as a dependency to your project.If you are using Eclipse then add the Zxing as libary and add that library to your project.If you are using Android Studio

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.0'
}
```

add this line in your gradle file.

Comment: Thanks! I might have guessed it. :)